# Crystal Report number of pages according to field value

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

My first question, so please excuse any mistakes.

We have internal ID numbers for product that we are selling, composed of: [SalesOrder_Num]/[Num].
For each Id No. we offer a Test Certificate to the client. Test Certificate defines the suitable age of product, along with its technical specification. Multiple items (20-30) on sales order can have same technical specification, but different ID number. ID Number also becomes Certificate Number.
We need to print/pdf these test certificates using **Crystal Reports**. There is a custom made Certificate Window on which technical specs are manually typed, along with sales order number. We also fill in number of Certificates (= [Num]).
What we now want is: Print [Num] of records/PDF with Certificate Number incrementally increasing on each PDF - [SalesOrder_Num]/1,  [SalesOrder_Num]/2, ... ... ,[SalesOrder_Num]/[Num-1], [SalesOrder_Num]/[Num].

How is it possible?

Best Regards,
K

Comment: I don't know any suitable method from Crystal side. From database side, cross apply your query to some clever function, returning required quantity of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a REPEATER table with a single column (How_Many) that looks like this:
How_Many
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc..
Now, in your report, add the Repeater Table and add a join condition of:
Order.quantity >= Repeater.How_Many

If the ">=" join option is not available, remove the join to the REPEATER table and create this condition in the Record Selection condition:
{Order.quantity} >= {Repeater.How_Many}

This would cause each order to be duplicated as many times as the value of {Order.quantity}.

If you are restricted to using an equal join, you can also modify the repeater table to include N records for each quantity N:
1
2
2
3
3
3
...

This would cause each order to be duplicated as many times as the value of {Order.quantity}.

If you need to print "N of M" modify the repeater table to look like this:
N   M
1   1
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
and use an equal join to the N column.

An alternative solution is to use a 3rd-party Crystal tool. At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers) provides the functionality you are seeking (without needing to add a Repeater table to your database).